# Linker warning - Linking two modules of different target triples

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, llvm, ld

I got this linker warning:

```
WARNING: Linking two modules of different target triples!
```

It sounds serious but not really clear to me.

What is the problem and what should I do about it?

Btw, I'm using Xcode 3.2.5 and LLVM Compiler 1.6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target triple is a string describing the machine, such as `i686-apple-darwin9.5.0`. Most likely, you are mixing object files that had been built on different OSX releases; this is harmless (except that the resulting binary may require the maximum of these versions).

Comment: This is an error from the LLVM bitcode linker. It sounds like the OP is building with Link-Time Optimization enabled. Note that the triple will be canonicalized to something like `i686-apple-darwin9` to eliminate the minor revision. I've just filed http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8865 to suggest improving the error.